# Search Lucene.Net for fieldname which has value (x or y or z) and more

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have a field that is numeric. 
It can have some values; `0,7,12,16,18,101 ++`, but only ONE of these values per document

I want to retrieve the documents with values 7,12 and 16

I have tried using the BooleanQuery with Terms, which I have had no luck with. I believe that is because I'm not searching for a string.

I have tried using the `NumericRangeFilter.NewIntRange(`, and setting min and max value to the actual value I'm interested in retrieving.

I have this code:

```
public static Query AddRangeFilter(this Query query, string fieldName, IEnumerable<int> validAlternatives)
{
    if (!validAlternatives.Any())
        return query;

    foreach (var alternative in validAlternatives)
    {
        var filter = NumericRangeFilter.NewIntRange(fieldName, 1, alternative, alternative, true, true);
        query = new FilteredQuery(query, filter);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Which works just fine if I send in a singular number in the list. But if i send in more, it does not work, naturally, because it is then looking for t.ex. a document with values 7 & 12, which does not exists, since all documents only have a singular number.

How can i make this search for 7 OR 12? 
Mind you, `this Query query` in `AddRangeFilter` already contains parts of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of solving it. It's not perfect, and it is likely very inefficient if you have more of these.

```
public static Query AddRangeFilter(this Query query, string fieldName, IEnumerable<int> validAlternatives)
{
    if (!validAlternatives.Any())
        return query;

    var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery { MinimumNumberShouldMatch = 1 };
    foreach (var alternative in validAlternatives)
    {
        var thing = NumericRangeFilter.NewIntRange(fieldName, 1, alternative, alternative, true, true);
        booleanQuery.Add(new FilteredQuery(query, thing), Occur.SHOULD);
    }

    return booleanQuery;
}
```

If there are any better answers, I am very interested in seeing them.